# How to convert kubectl create -f file.yaml to curl

Tags: curl, kubernetes

I am trying to solve how to convert
`kubectl create -f file.yaml` to `curl` eqivalent. I have obviously managed to do something like that

```
curl -ik \ 
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

However, when it comes to `curl -X POST ...` request, I was not able to figure out how to make **curl** substitute

```
kubectl create -f file.yaml --v=8
```

Comment: this might be useful https://nieldw.medium.com/curling-the-kubernetes-api-server-d7675cfc398c

Comment: Hello, have you tried this way?: `curl -X POST https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Content-Type: application/yaml" --data-binary @pod.yaml --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` where @pod.yaml is your `YAML` manifest.

Comment: yes guys I tried all of this but I need to specifically `call kubectl create -f filename`

Comment: Could you please put more details, what so special about `kubectl create -f filename`, so that mentioned options didn't meet your expectation? It's not really clear from the question. Example with the sample input and expected output might also help to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the question of the following post is:

> How can I send a request with `curl` that will create a resource in Kubernetes cluster with a specified `YAML` file.

Dissecting the example from my comment:

> curl -X POST https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Content-Type: application/yaml" --data-binary @pod.yaml --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

- `-X POST`:

  - send a `HTTP` request with `POST` method
- `https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods`:

  - location to send the request to
- `-H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"`:

  - set the header with a token for authorization
- `-H "Content-Type: application/yaml"`:

  - set the header with a request body type (`YAML`)
- `--data-binary @pod.yaml`:

  - specify the filename that will be send with a request
- `--cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`:

  - use the specified certificate file to verify the peer

> Disclaimer!
>
> This example assumes that the request comes from a `Pod` and all of the necessary permissions are assigned to a `ServiceAccount`.

Creating different resources like `Deployments`, `Configmaps` will require to send the request to a different `URL` for example:

- `Deployment`: `apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments`
- `Configmap`: `api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps`
- etc.

> A side note!
>
> You will also need to consider the `namespace` you are sending the request to as sending the resource to the wrong namespace will deny its creation.

Following command should be helpful on how the `curl` should look like (path wise):

- `kubectl create -f file_name.yaml -v=9`

---

Additional resources:

- *[Curl.se: Docs: Manpage](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Generated: Kubernetes-api: v1.20](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/)*